# How the LLL algorithm produce short and nearly orthogonal vectors?

Tags: math, cryptography, linear-algebra, computer-science, mathematical-lattices

I was studying the LLL algorithm from Steven. Galbraith, Mathematics of Public Key Cryptography. They stated that "**the lattice basis is close to orthogonal if the lengths of the Gram-Schmidt vectors do not decrease too rapidly**".
I am unable to understand this statement and also if the parameter **delta in the LLL algorithm becomes less than 1/4**, then what will happen?
Please explain to me.

I understand how the length of the basis vectors reduces by imposing the size condition of LLL reduced basis, but **how they become close to orthogonal** and checking Lovasz condition on Gram Schmidt vectors **how increasing ordering of length of the original vectors** is possible that part is not clear.

Comment: This question probably belongs on the Mathematics group where there might be someone who knows the answer and can explain it well enough to help. It is a very specialised mathematical argument that I find very hard to follow and cannot explain. I'm interested in LLL as applied to optimising floating point coefficients for polynomial and rational function approximation. It is claimed to make quite a difference at finding a near global optimum because of its nearly orthogonal behaviour. Basically it finds the right places to search for a better solution. Conventional algorithms get stuck...